# Does LESS have an "extend" feature?

Tags: css, sass, less, extend

SASS has a feature called `@extend` which allows a selector to inherit the properties of another selector, but without copying the properties (like mixins).

Does LESS have this feature as well?

Comment: For clarification, the other question references does NOT ask the same thing. This question is simple: "Does LESS have an extend feature?". The other question is asking something that requires much more thought regarding styling decisions.

Comment: ... to add to my last comment, the other question includes the "coding-style" tag which further supports my point.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Yes, Less.js introduced [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) in [v1.4.0](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

```
:extend()
```

Rather than implementing the at-rule (`@extend`) syntax used by SASS and Stylus, LESS implemented the pseudo-class syntax, which gives LESS's implementation the flexibility to be applied either directly to a selector itself, or inside a statement. So both of these will work:

```
.sidenav:extend(.nav) {...}
```

or

```
.sidenav {
    &:extend(.nav);
    ...
}
```

Additionally, you can use the `all` directive to extend "nested" classes as well:

```
.sidenav:extend(.nav all){};
```

And you can add a comma-separated list of classes you wish to extend:

```
.global-nav {
    &:extend(.navbar, .nav all, .navbar-fixed-top all, .navbar-inverse);
    height: 70px;
}
```

When extending nested selectors you should notice the differences:

nested selectors `.selector1` and `selector2`:

```
.selector1 {
  property1: a;
   .selector2 {
    property2: b;
   }
}
```

Now `.selector3:extend(.selector1 .selector2){};` outputs:

```
.selector1 {
  property1: a;
}
.selector1 .selector2,
.selector3 {
  property2: b;
}
```

, `.selector3:extend(.selector1 all){};` outputs:

```
.selector1,
.selector3 {
  property1: a;
}
.selector1 .selector2,
.selector3 .selector2 {
  property2: b;
}
```

,`.selector3:extend(.selector2){};` outputs

```
.selector1 {
  property1: a;
}
.selector1 .selector2 {
  property2: b;
}
```

and finally `.selector3:extend(.selector2 all){};`:

```
.selector1 {
  property1: a;
}
.selector1 .selector2,
.selector1 .selector3 {
  property2: b;
}
```

Comment: "LESS's syntax is more "faithful" to traditional CSS than the at-rule (`@extend`) syntax implemented by SASS and Stylus, which is typically reserved for giving instructions or directives to the CSS parser in the browser." <- what the heck is this supposed to mean?  Smells like marketing speak.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26336/discussion-between-steveax-and-jonschlinkert)

Comment: @cimmanon I guess you're right, I didn't mean it to sound that way. But there is a lot of controversy about Less's syntax, seemingly because people expected Less to use the same syntax as SASS. But in CSS, pseuso-selectors are used for pattern matching rules to  determine which style rules apply to elements in the document tree, whereas at-rules are used for "higher-level" directives (as I mentioned). So maybe I should edit the answer to provide that detail? Or is that another question: "Why did LESS choose the pseudo-selector syntax?"

Comment: @jonschlinkert can you be more informational about the `all` directive? Like good examples of when to use it and when not to use it. Also, when is [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/) going to be updated with new docs and a new download? 1.3.3 is still up. Thanks!

Comment: you should really update the less documentation online, I cannot see anything about :extend() and it would have been good to know earlier

Comment: The documentation, as with the code, is community maintained. These kinds of suggestions would be great to have on the actual repo, and pull requests are always welcome ;-)

Comment: I am not sure about bug reports for less but this did not work for my selector `h1,h1,h3` but it did work if I added spaces after the commas ie `h1, h1, h3`

Comment: @Josh'Bambi'Bambrick, it would be great if you could bring that up on the Less.js issues over on GitHub. that sounds like a bug. thanks

Comment: Less' syntax is *not* more faithful to CSS. In fact, Sass' `@extend` (and more) is a proposed addition to the CSS specification: https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-extend-rule

Comment: Shame it doesn't work, `.noButtonStyle();` works but `&:extend(.noButtonStyle);` does nothing in the same place

Comment: I found this only works when the classes are in the same css file.  even importing another style sheet into the file won't work

Answer (score 7):

### Easy way to extend a function in Less framework

```
.sibling-1 {
    color: red
}
.sibling-2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    .sibling-1();
}
```

> Output

```
.sibling-1 {
  color: red
}
.sibling-2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: red
}
```

Refer https://codepen.io/sprushika/pen/MVZoGB/

Answer (score 0):

Less allows us to do :extend(.class) or :extend(#id)