# Use selector name as variable in LESS mixin

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to create a mixin within LESS that will use it's selector name as a variable inside of the mixing. The mixin should look something like this, but I cannot find the exact syntax for it or if it's even possible:

```
.bg{
 background-image: url('images/@{SELECTORNAME}.png');
}

#header{
  .bg;
}
```

results in:

```
#header{
    background-image: url('images/header.png');
}
```

I'm thinking this isn't possible, plus what would happen if the selecter was something like:

```
div#menu ul li
```

That wouldn't really work but perhaps anyone knows of an alternative, wether this is possible in any other preprocessor.

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't use ID's in CSS selector's

Comment: @koningdavid: that is a philosophical position on how CSS should be used, a position with which I happen to disagree. There are some valid cases for using ID's in CSS selectors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### You cannot "read" the selector name.

However, you can *build the selector* in conjunction to linking with the file name in a mixin, something like so:

**LESS**

```css
.buildSelectorConnection(@selectorName, @pre: ~'') {
  @{pre}@{selectorName} {
     background-image: url('images/@{selectorName}.png');
  }
}

.buildSelectorConnection(header, ~'#');
.buildSelectorConnection(do-a-class, ~'.');
```

**CSS Output**

```css
#header {
  background-image: url('images/header.png');
}
.do-a-class {
  background-image: url('images/do-a-class.png');
}
```

However, it would take quite a bit more logic, decision making on your part, and some javascript coding in LESS if you wanted to make such a thing be able to handle something like `div#menu ul li` where the actual filename generated was something like `div-menu-ul-li.png`.

### Nevertheless...

Something like this could be done:

**LESS**

```css
.buildSelectorConnection(@selectorName, @pre: ~'', @post: ~'') {
  @{pre}@{selectorName}@{post} {
     background-image: url('images/@{selectorName}.png');
  }
}

.buildSelectorConnection(menu, ~'div#', ~' ul li');
```

**CSS Output**

```css
div#menu ul li {
  background-image: url('images/menu.png');
}
```

This basically lets you build any selector string, but the file name itself will only be that initial selector passed in, which needs to be something valid for a file name.

Comment: Dang, thats it! Thanks Scott! Some people might think this isn't very good practise, it probably isn't, but I still like it.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash: That's because SimpLESS is way behind in LESS releases. [Currently SimpLESS is on release 1.4 which is stated to only be using LESS 1.3.](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) As of this comment, [LESS itself is on 1.5](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). It is actually [LESS 1.3.1](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#131) that the selector syntax I use in this answer was introduced (`@{pre}@{selectorName}`). So if SimpLESS is about a year behind LESS releases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, LESS just introduced an extend feature in 1.4.0.

Check out the answer to this question here: [Does LESS have an "extend" feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464982/does-less-have-an-extend-feature)

Comment: extend does not seem to be the function I am looking for. For what I understand, extend extends a previously defined mixin, creating another usuable mixin with additional CSS properties.