# Output LESS variable name as string

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to reference a variable name as an actual string of text within a content property, rather than the value of the variable.

For context, I'm trying to set up a color palette for a style guide. Colors are defined as variables and then listed using the `content` property. @rocketRed may compile as "#ff0048", but how do I compile @rocketRed as "@rocketRed"?

And if that's not enough, it's probably further complicated by me trying to pass the variable through a mixin. Otherwise it'd sort of defeat the purpose.

Here's an example:

```
@rocketRed:#ff0048;

.mixin(@color) {
  &:before {content: "@color"};
  &:after {content: "@{color}"};
}

.test {
  .mixin(@rocketRed)
}
```

Which compiles to

```
.test:before {
  content: "@color";
}
.test:after {
  content: "#ff0048";
}
```

The `:before` clearly doesn't work. What I'd really like that to compile to is:

`content: "@rocketRed";`

I suppose part of the problem is the variables automatically compile. @color -> @rocketRed -> #ff0048.  Somehow I'd need to just reference what @color is referencing, and stop it there, by converting it to a string.

This is the closest thing I've come across, which really isn't too applicable, but I'd imagine the solution (if at all possible) would be somewhat similar: [Use selector name as variable in LESS mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235676/use-selector-name-as-variable-in-less-mixin)

I realize I'm probably pushing some boundaries on how variables work, but sometimes pushing boundaries works out!

Comment: Consider a code like `.mixin(1 + 2);` to guess why what you want is just impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is simply impossible. If you really need something like this do it in reverse (i.e. by converting a string to the corresponding variable value), e.g.:

```
@rocketRed: #ff0048;

.mixin(@color) {
  color: @@color;                // variable value
  &:before {content: "@{color}"} // variable name
}

.usage {
    .mixin(rocketRed);
}
```

Or alternatively (if you like more quotes in your code):

```
@rocketRed: #ff0048;

.mixin(@color) {
  color: @@color;            // variable value
  &:before {content: @color} // variable name
}

.usage {
    .mixin("rocketRed");
}
```

### ---

Assuming you need this for some debug/logging purposes, it can be optimized to consume only one pseudo-element:

```
@rocketRed: #ff0048;

.mixin(@color) {
    &:before {
        content: %("@%a: %a",
            @color, @@color);
    }
}

.usage {
    .mixin(rocketRed);
}
```

-> css:

```
.usage:before {
  content: "@rocketRed: #ff0048";
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. I always forget to just try reversing my logic. It seems quite often that simple tactic finds itself a solution. The next issue I ran into was showing the hex as content, and I couldn't get the @@ trick to work without quotes. While your suggestion of combining both name and value in one pseudo element didn't quite work for what I was trying to do (I want them separate so they can be styled independently) it still seems to offer a good solution for that new problem. Here's how/where I put it to use: http://codepen.io/chasebank/pen/ZYNyNY

Comment: > I couldn't get the @@ trick to work without quotes. - It's just because at the codepen they use some older Less version where color keywords (e.g. `blue`) in `@@` are interpreted as a raw color value (instead the actual identifier) thus `@@<raw-color-value>` -> `@undefined`.

Comment: Ah! Interesting, I'll have to check into that some more and see what else is new. Thanks for that info