# CSS class alias

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to generate css class alias?

Details:

I'm using `bootstrap.css` framework and I've got some html that I **cannot** change. This html has some container with class `"awesomnes-container"` and some items inside with like `"awesomnes-item"`.

Lets say I want container to bevahe exacly like `.row` class and item like `.col-lg-12`

I know its pretty simple to add needed classes with **javascript** but I find it not 100% stable solution and in case of failture the consequences would be huge.

I also dont want to modify oryginal bootstrap file as It would be nightmare for updates. I'm using some 'overlay' css file loaded after bootstrap.

Comment: So you can't modify the HTML, won't modify the CSS, and don't want to use js?

Comment: why don't you use jquery to add the class to all required elements. $(".awesomnes-container").addClass("row")

Comment: I can add CSS, not modify bootstrap core .css (I've wrote I'm using css overlay on it). Cheers. GP - I've wrote why.

Comment: Pure CSS doesn't have any way to alias one class to another. Instead, HTML allows you to apply multiple classes to the same element, and the cascading rules determine which rules take precedence.

Comment: @Blazemonger true enough, 'pure CSS' doesn't — but Bootstrap ships with LESS, which does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bootstrap's CSS is written in LESS form by default, so it would be better to include an extra .less file and use its [extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464982/does-less-have-an-extend-feature) function to map your HTML's classes to the Bootstrap classes you want them to implement.

In this case, you'd be looking at:

```
.awesomnes-container {
    &:extend(.row);
}

.awesomnes-item{
    &:extend(.col-lg-12);
}
```