# Simplify the group of classes and pseudo classes in Less

Tags: css, less

How could I simplify this expression?

```css
.rss,
.rss:hover {
    background-color: #ff8900;
}
```

If there is any way of using like this?

```css
.rss, &:hover {
    background-color: #ff8900;
}
```

Comment: Why even set a hover if the background color is going to be the same?

Comment: Any reason why you want to simplify it? It already looks pretty compact. Is there something more to what you are trying than given in question?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid duplicating code, so, this is small part of it

Comment: `&_twitter,
 &_twitter:hover {
  background-color: #55acee;
  background-image: url('Twitter.svg');
  .noSVG('Sprite.png', -1942px, -141px);
 }

 &_facebook,
 &_facebook:hover {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  background-image: url('Facebook.svg');
  .noSVG('Sprite.png', -1940px, -45px);
 }

 &_youtube,
 &_youtube:hover {
  background-color: #cc181e;
  background-image: url('YouTube.svg');
  .noSVG('Sprite.png', -1939px, -239px);
 }`

Comment: Ok, in that case one more question before I suggest any sample. If the main class and its hover always have the same set of props, you could use the way Hashem has mentioned. Another method might be to use `extend`.

Comment: Yes, Hashem seems to be right. But it doesn't realy simplify. Anyway thx =)

Comment: As I said, your original code is already as close to compact as possible mate. So I am not sure if you could simplify it any further. The only alternate to Hashem's answer is using `extend` and it doesn't really simplify much either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it does simplify, but one option could be using [parent selector `&`](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) as follows:

```css
.rss {
   &, &:hover {
    background-color: #ff8900;
  }
}
```

In this approach you could specify which declarations should be shared between `.rss` and `.rss:hover`.

---

Another option could be [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature)ing the `.rss` as [@Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) pointed that out:

```css
.rss {
  background-color: #ff8900;
  &:hover:extend(.rss) {};
}
```

[This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464982/does-less-have-an-extend-feature) is helpful if both `.rss` and `.rss:hover` should have the same set of CSS declarations.

---

As can be seen, in this particular instance both of the above methods don't really *simplify* the selectors but they might help in more complex situations.

Comment: Don't want to add another answer when it is not much of an improvement on the current answer mate. So leaving my [sample](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/lbtEK) using the `extend` function as a comment here. Please feel free to add it to the answer if you are Ok with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually is something like this:

```
.rss {
   &:hover {background-color: #ff8900;
}
```

It adds the :hover to the rss, creating both

> .rss
>
> .rss:hover

classes to your css file