# Add the styles from one class to another class with LESS

Tags: less

I have 2 classes with different styles. Can I apply the styles from one class to another when within a media query with LESS?

So with the following CSS an element with a class of .one is blue but not bold. With a set media query I also want it to be bold and 2ems.

```
.one {
 color: blue;
}

.two {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Not sure of the exact requirement but if you just want some extra properties, it can be done with pure CSS itself. If you want to define a class (or mixin) and re-use it then you could use Peter's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

:extend can do this. In the code below if .class2 is in a media query then for that width the styles from .class will be applied.

```
.class {
  some rules here 
}

.class2 {
    &:extend(.class);
    ...
}
```

[Does LESS have an "extend" feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464982/does-less-have-an-extend-feature)

Answer (score 16):

Try

```
.one {
 color: blue;
}

.two {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2em;
}
@media screen {
   .one{
       .one;
       .two;
   }
}
```

will create this css:

```
.one {
  color: blue;
}
.two {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}
@media screen {
  .one {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to apply the rule within a media query

Comment: @jdln ok, check it now.

Comment: I need to do this without adding a class to the HTML. Reason being I want to sometimes add the class in different media queries, and sometimes with JS. It will keep my LESS much cleaner if I can simply extend the styles from the class in a media query.

Comment: You dont have to add a class to the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mixin and a variable for the color

```
@default_color : "#000";
@color : blue;

.font-style(@c: @default_color) {
  color: @c;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.one {
 color: @color;
}

.two {
  .font-style()
}

@media (max-width:420px) { 
  .one {
    .font-style(@color)
  }
}
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anpsmn/pen/ByWoaY)

In the demo above, resize the window to lesser width and you will find the text changing it's style.