# Bootstrap: Having navigation with DIVs (or other elements) instead of UL > LI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to have my own markup

```
<nav>
<my-list class="nav-justified">
    <item class="nav-item">Text 1</item>
    <item class="nav-item">Text 2</item>
</my-list>
</nav>
```

I cannot do that right now because bootstrap is targetting LIs inside  by the element name only and not by a class

for example

```
.nav-justified {
  width: 100%;

  > li {
    float: none;
    > a {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you put your code in jsfiddle or jsbin, so we can see what you are trying to do?  You tagged your question with Angular2, but you are asking a Bootstrap CSS question, so obviously there is some confusion there :)

Comment: Are you using just the CSS or are you utilizing their SASS?

Comment: no, I a m using LESS

Comment: @Brunis: yeah, my mistake... somehow the form didn't clear after my previous question ;) sorry for the confusion... this is strictly bootstrap/"html" ;)

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu: In theory I could change the nav.less in bootstrap's code... but don't really want to do that... but it seems I will have to overwrite it it with mine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you have to add some CSS or change existing one.

As I'm using SASS a lot, I was thinking about [extending a class/selector](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-extend-nobody-told-you/) — but as you are using LESS you need [the equivalent `:extend(.class)`-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464982/does-less-have-an-extend-feature).

So you could just add another LESS-file in your project and in there set up your markup and extend the existing Bootstrap-Styles:

```
my-list:extend(.nav-justified) {...}

.nav-item:extend(.nav-justified > li) {...}
```

*(something in this direction, depending on your needs // code is untested)*

By extending the existing selectors and working in a separate file your project should stay clean and you could re-use your work in other projects where you use Bootstrap.

[More about the LESS extend feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing ;) just wasn't expressing myself correctly ;) Well, cheers for the input! appreciated!